# Might my file be too big to be written with 'writeRaster' in R?

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff, file-size, bigtiff

I am trying to write a GeoTiff of a rasterstack that I created after some calculations. I am not quite sure how big the output-file might be. But I assume it has more than 4 GB. I can plot the stacked file but everytime I try to write the file, R ist busy for several hours and I cannot spot anything in my output folder. I tried the code with some smaller images and it seems to work fine.

Is there a size-limit for 'writeRaster' in R and, if so, is there a workaround?

I read there is BigTiff, but it seems not to be supported within the formats of writeRaster.

```
 rs <- writeRaster(rasterstack, filename= 
                paste(getwd(),sprintf("/Raster/%s/rasterstack_%s.tif", 
                                      year,year),sep = ''),format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: I always tile very large raster data prior to analysis/processing. For example: https://www.r-bloggers.com/use-gdal-from-r-console-to-split-raster-into-tiles/

Comment: Try writing smaller rasters made of random numbers and seeing how long it takes. Keep doubling the resolution or number of layers and writing and time it, then see if it fails if the output is >4Gb...

Comment: What is dim() of the raster and what is the actual code used to write? What is filename() of the raster, if any? Make sure write to different disk if it already has a filename

Comment: On Windows if you check the location of `Sys.getenv('TMPDIR')` you should be able to see if R is writing temp files (could be TIF or GRD) or has simply frozen. Also, check whether you're specifying an appropriate `datatype` parameter to `writeRaster()`, it defaults to 'FLT4S' which you may not need. You can save a lot of space/time that way. Lastly, consider whether you really need a multiband GeoTIFF. Would writing out each layer of the stack separately be ok?

Comment: Thanks for all the information and tips. I'll try to keep you updated about your answer as soon as i figured out what helped best. The dimension of the file is 20000 x 25000
It seems to constantly work, as the space on the disk with my temp folder is getting constantly smaller. Just the output (which should be saved on another disk) is not appearing. 
I put the code of the writing command in my question.

Comment: It just created an output. The code seems to work and there seems not to be a limit of 4 GB for GeoTiff by writeRaster. My output had 41.3 GB. It is not very practical though and I would recommend to go for a solution by Aaron or obrl_soil and tile the raster or keep the bands separate.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I found this solution works fine with me https://stackoverflow.com/a/40762304/4004373